# Should operator !() be defined in a class if bool() operator is already defined?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, logical-operators, negation

I have a simple class which is a concrete class and is not designed to be inherited. Also I want to be able to say !myobject where myobject is an instance of this class. I've already define `operator bool()`. Should I also define `bool operator!()`?

Here is trivial example of the class:

```
class Test
{
  public:
    ...
    explicit operator bool() {
      return error_ == 0;
    }

    bool operator!() {
      return error_ != 0;
    }

  private:
    int error_;
};
```

I tried it as `!myobject` and it works independent of `!()` operator is being defined or not.
Looks like it is a silly question, but I couldn't find an answer for it.

Comment: `operator bool()` is all you need.

Comment: The two operators *could* give different results, if you so decided. The `std::basic_ios` class has both [`operator bool()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) and [`operator !()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!)

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to have both for performance reasons. Knowing your are in the context of evaluating logical negation can allow you to short-circuit a complete check that you'd have to do for `operator bool`. Not a usual occurrence, but worth keeping in mind. For your simple class in the example, you don't need to overload both.

Comment: Side note: they should `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C++ 17 Standard (8.3.1 Unary operators)

> 9 **The operand of the logical negation operator ! is contextually
> converted to bool** (Clause 7); its value is true if the converted
> operand is false and false otherwise. The type of the result is bool.

So there is no need to overload the operator !() when there is the conversion operator to the type bool.

Comment: Thank you. Does the same work for C++11 standard?

Comment: @ivoriik As far as I remember it is valid also for C++ 11.

Answer (score 0):

Use the operator bool() const in your class:

```
 explicit operator bool() const {
     return error_ == 0;
 }
```

and no need to define overload `!()`.